# Distance from Terminal 2 and 3 for people who are arriving in Dubai

Tags: airports, dubai

I am arriving in Dubai on 25 Sept at 08:05 terminal 3 with Emirate From London  and My wife arrives on the same day from Dar es Salaam with Flydubai at terminal 2, It's our first time in Dubai and we want to meet together before going to the hotel, How far is from terminal 2 and 3 and advise us how can we easily meet ?

Answer (score 2):

> **Transferring to or from Emirates Terminal 3**
>
> For your convenience there are buggies to transport you within the terminal buildings, but not between the terminals.
>
> If you are transferring from an Emirates flight to a flydubai flight departing from Terminal 2, you have to use a dedicated bus service to the F Gates in Terminal 2. This bus ride can take up to 40 minutes.
>
> If you are connecting on any other airline flight, another dedicated bus service will transfer you to the D gates in Terminal 1.

[Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/emirates-terminal-3/finding-your-way.aspx)

So, take the 40 minutes Bus ride to reach Terminal 2 and follow the exit signs. Pre coordinate a spot outside Terminal 2's exit gates.